# Chaining array into new split function call

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays

I have the following and am trying to split on `'.'` and then split the returned first part on `'-'` and return the last of the first part. I want to return `447`.

```
a="cat-vm-447.json".split('.').split('-')
```

Also, how would I do this as a regular expression? I have this:

```
a="cat-vm-447.json".split(/-[\d]+./)
```

but this is splitting on the value. I want to return the number.

I can do this:

```
a="cat-vm-447.json".slice(/[\d]+/)
```

and this gives me back `447` but would really like to specify that the `-` and `.` surround it. Adding those in regex return them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First question. Split returns an array, so you need to use [Array#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) to get first(0) or last(-1) elements of this array. Alternatives is [Array#first](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-first) and [Array#last](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-last) methods.

```
a="cat-vm-447.json".split('.')[0].split('-')[-1] # => "447"
```

Second question. You can match your number into group and then get it from the response (it will have index 1. Item with index 0 will be full match ("-447." in your case). You can use [String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) or [String#match](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-match) (among others) methods to match your regex.

```
"cat-vm-447.json"[/-(\d+)\./, 1] # => "447"
# or
"cat-vm-447.json".match(/-(\d+)\./)[1] # => "447"
```

Comment: If the filename is guaranteed to only have one string of digits, `"cat-vm-447.json"[/\d+/]` will return `"447"` without the need to use a capture.

Comment: @theTinMan, yes, but OP *would really like to specify that the - and . surround it* (from the question)

Answer (score 1):

[Split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) returns an array, so you need to specify the index for the next split.

```
a="cat-vm-447.json".split('.').first.split('-').last
```

For the regular expression, you need to wrap what you want to capture in parentheses.

```
/-(\d+)\./
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "cat-vm-447.json"
b = a.match(/-(\d+)\./)
p b[0] # => 447
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
if "cat-vm-447.json" =~ /([\d]+)/
   p $1
else
   p "No matches"
end
```

The parentheses in the regex extract the result in the $1 variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you split your string second time, you actually trying to split Array instead of String.

```
ruby-1.9.3-head :003 > "cat-vm-447.json".split('.')
# => ["cat-vm-447", "json"]
```

In regexp case, you can use `/[-.]/`

```
ruby-1.9.3-head :008 > "cat-vm-447.json".split(/[-.]/)
# => ["cat", "vm", "447", "json"] 
ruby-1.9.3-head :009 > "cat-vm-447.json".split(/[-.]/)[2]
# => "447"
```